# Using the SUM function in vb6 to sum elements in an array

Tags: vb6, sum

I need to sum over a subset of elements in an array of doubles. As a simple example 
consider an array of 10 elements:

```
  Dim Array(1 To 10) As Double
```

where each element has been assigned some value. Is there a function in VB that will sum the first 5 elements? Obviously this can be solved using a loop but is there a one line solution? I would like to keep my code consise. I have tried using SUM but without success.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please specify whether you are using vb6 or vb.net? In the case of vb.net and framework 3.5 you could use Linq to sum after 'taking' the first 5 items.

Comment: I've just edited my post: I'm using vb6

Comment: If your purpose is to reuse the code you might want to create your own methods to implement Take and Sum methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built in summing function in VB6 that does what you want, but you can write one easily:

```
Public Function SumRange(ByRef dblArray() As Double, Optional ByVal StartRange As Long = -1, Optional ByVal Length As Long = -1)

   '-1 on StartRange indicates start at low bound
   If StartRange = -1 Then
      StartRange = LBound(dblArray)
   End If

   '-1 on Length indicates to span all elements to the end of the array
   If Length = -1 Then
      Length = UBound(dblArray) - StartRange - 1
   End If

   Dim dTotal As Double
   Dim lNdx As Long

   For lNdx = StartRange To StartRange + Length - 1
      dTotal = dTotal + dblArray(lNdx)
   Next lNdx

   SumRange = dTotal

End Function
```

Please be aware I did not sytaz check this, so watch for typos.  It can be used as follows:

```
dResult = SumRange(myArray) 'summ all

dResult = SumRange(myArray, 3) 'sum all starting at offset 3

dResult = SumRange(myArray, , 2) 'sum the the first 2 elements

dResult = SumRange(myArray, 2, 4) 'sum a range start at 2 and with length of 4
```

You could modify the method to take another optional boolean to specifies if you will tolerate (ignore) out-of-bounds.  Right now an error would be reaised if you asked to sum more elements than exist in the array.